# Repeat an increment of loop

Tags: java

For my science fair project, I'm wanting to give a graphical update to a French-teaching program that's so old it's emulated in DosBOX. That's all well and good but I'm having problems. I'm writing the base logic of the program in a console application just to get that together. I've created a Question class that's in a array list/collection known as "test1".

I have a loop that iterates through the list and with each iteration, it runs another method called evaluate:

```
public static boolean evaluate(Question question, Scanner scanner)
{
    System.out.println(question.getPhrase()); // prints the question
    String answer = scanner.nextLine(); // gets the answer
    if (answer.compareTo(question.getCorrectAnswer()) == 0)
        return true; // compares the answer to the correct answer w/i the current instance of "Question"
    else
        return false; // if it's not right, returns "false" meaning the question wasn't correct
}
```

The loop looks as such:

```
    for (Question question : test1)
    {
        if (evaluate(question, scan))
            {
                incorrect = 0;
                continue;
            }

        else
            {
                incorrect++;
                System.out.println(incorrect);
            }

        if (incorrect == 3)
            System.out.println("you have failed");
            break;
    }
```

I want to make it so that if you answer a question incorrectly, it spits out the phrase again and increases "incorrect" by 1 and, if you hit 3, terminates the list (I think I've got this implemented correctly if I could just get it to repeat the question). Right now it moves to the next item in the list and thus the next question even if and I don't want that.

Sorry if my code is awful, I'm still relatively new to programming.

Comment: You need another loop inside the loop you already have, that repeats the current question until it's answered correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing a `foreach` loop the way you're doing it now, you can do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < test1.size(); i++) {
    Question question = test1.get(i);
    if (evaluate(question, scan)) {
        ...
    } else {
        incorrect++;
        test1.add(question);
    }

    if (incorrect == 3) { ... }
}
```

This is assuming you're using a data structure that uses `size()` and `add()` as methods; you can adjust it to what you're using.

This will repeat questions later, though not immediately after. If you want to repeat it immediately after, just decrement `i--` in the `else` case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < test1.size(); i++) {
    Question question = test1.get(i);
    if (evaluate(question, scan)) {
        ...
    } else {
        incorrect++;
        i--;
    }

    if (incorrect == 3) { ... }
}
```

You can also nest a loop for the `else` case:

```
for (Question question : test1) {
    boolean passed = True;
    incorrect = 0;
    while (!evaluate(question, scan)) {
        incorrect++;
        if (incorrect == 3) { passed = False; break; }
    }

    if (!passed) { System.out.println("you have failed"); break; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a while loop inside of the for loop that says if the question isn't answered correctly, then repeat so that way in each question the question will be asked until its correct. Keep everything inside the for loop in the while loop that you should create:

```
for (Question question : test1)
{
    while(!evaluate(question, scan)) {
    if (evaluate(question, scan))
        {
            incorrect = 0;
            continue;
        }

    else
        {
            incorrect++;
            System.out.println(incorrect);
        }

    if (incorrect == 3)
        System.out.println("you have failed");
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: This didn't work exactly as I'd have liked it to but it still did give me input on how to possibly implement similar in the future, so thank you! I hadn't thought of it like that. I knew I needed a second loop but wasn't exactly sure what to do.